# Scrolling without animation JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to do a sharp upward scrolling.

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0)
```

scrolls smoothly, how do I scroll up without animation?

Comment: Use `scroll-behavior: auto` in you CSS

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You pass an object instead of position, like this:

```html
element.scrollTo({
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  behavior: 'instant'
});
```

behavior is default selected by browser, in chrome it uses smooth, where en webkit browser, default is instant.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;` for Chrome, Firefox, IE, Opera and Edge Browsers and
`document.body.scrollTop = 0` for Safari Browser

Answer (score 0):

```
scroll-behavior: smooth;
```

You can use this for smoothly.

if you don't want to be smoothly, use this:

```
scroll-behavior: auto;
```